# Rails flash messages fired with javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, flash-message

I have a website with two templates

One template handles receives flash messages regularly.
The other template needs messages fired via a javascript:

```
var notyfy = notyfy(
{
    text: 'Hello I am an error',
    type: 'error' // alert|error|success
});
```

I have build a `flash_helper`. This helper watches which template is active and should send back the right "flash message":

- I don't know how to send the javascript within the view_helper

Here is my flash_helper.rb

```
# called via <%= flash_messages %>

module FlashHelper

  def flash_messages
    return if flash.empty?

    if controller.send(:_layout) == "pro/application"
      flash.collect do |type, message|
        # HERE SHOULD THE MAGICK HAPPEN :-)
        javascript_tag "alert('All is good')", defer: 'defer'
      end
    else
      flash.collect do |type, message|
        content_tag(:div, :class => "notification-box notification-box-#{type}") do
          content_tag(:p) do
            content_tag(:i, nil, class: "icon-ok") +
                message
          end +
              link_to("#", class: "notification-close notification-close-#{type}") do
                content_tag(:i, nil, class: "icon-remove")
              end
        end
      end.join("\n").html_safe
    end
  end
end
```

My result is always a plain text:

`["<script defer=\"defer\" type=\"text/javascript\">\n//<![CDATA[\nalert('All is good')\n//]]>\n</script>", "<script defer=\"defer\" type=\"text/javascript\">\n//<![CDATA[\nalert('All is good')\n//]]>\n</script>", "<script defer=\"defer\" type=\"text/javascript\">\n//<![CDATA[\nalert('All is good')\n//]]>\n</script>", "<script defer=\"defer\" type=\"text/javascript\">\n//<![CDATA[\nalert('All is good')\n//]]>\n</script>"]`

Answer (score 0):

I got it working with `raw`

```
if controller.send(:_layout) == "pro/application"
    html = "<script>"
  flash.collect.with_index do |(type, message), i|
    html += "var notyfy#{i} = notyfy({"
    html += "text: '#{message}',"
    html += "type: '#{type}'"
    html += "});"
  end
    html += "</script>"
    return raw(html)
else
....
...
..
```